# How to make a bootstrap site stretch completely with no gutter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple site a guy made me using bootstrap. But it has a wide gutter on both sides, and I want to remove that, so the site will stretch from one side to the other.

I tried to do this by editing the css file, specifically the container size for each monitor size, and the padding (default is 15 px on both side).

This did make is slightly wider, but only slightly. Can anyone tell me what part of the css I can edit to do this? The gutters are a bit too wide for me!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content is surrounded by a div with `container` class, try to change it to `container-fluid`

[**Bootstrap doc**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid)

[Bootstrap 2.3.2 doc](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)

> Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing
>    your outermost .container to .container-fluid.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm! Now I just have to go back and put all the padding in I took out before haha. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helps you ;) You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick below the answer score if it's useful enough.